# How to split a Series in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20])
output:
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
4      5
5      6
6      7
7      8
8      9
9     10
10    11
11    12
12    13
13    14
14    15
15    16
16    17
17    18
18    19
19    20
dtype: int64
```

And I want to split the series to 4 series by the following:

- The first series will contain the numbers between 1-5
- The second series will contain the numbers between 6-10
- The third series will contain the numbers between 11-15
- The fourth series will contain the numbers between 16-20

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
               12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20])
s1 = s[0:5]
s2 = s[5:10]
s3 = s[10:15]
s4 = s[15:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy`'s `array_split()`

```
s_split = np.array_split(s, 4)
```

---

```
[0    1
 1    2
 2    3
 3    4
 4    5
 dtype: int64, 

 5     6
 6     7
 7     8
 8     9
 9    10
 dtype: int64,

 10    11
 11    12
 12    13
 13    14
 14    15
 dtype: int64,

 15    16
 16    17
 17    18
 18    19
 19    20
 dtype: int64]
```

Access them by `s_split[0],..s_split[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Use **numpy.array_split** (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html)!

this will split an array into multiple sub-arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20])
result = np.array_split(s, 4)
result
Out[2]: 
[0    1
 1    2
 2    3
 3    4
 4    5
 dtype: int64, 5     6
 6     7
 7     8
 8     9
 9    10
 dtype: int64, 10    11
 11    12
 12    13
 13    14
 14    15
 dtype: int64, 15    16
 16    17
 17    18
 18    19
 19    20
 dtype: int64]
```

Access them via looping over the list or via index e.g.

```
result[0]
Out[3]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
dtype: int64
```